# arrays.toString() custom formatting

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

How can I change the output from

```
[ua, disclaimer, ok, ua, navigation, fault, ua, fault, previous, ua, fault, previous]
```

to this

```
ua, disclaimer, ok ---> ua, navigation, fault ---> ua, fault, previous ---> ua, fault, previous
```

by varying this print statement

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))
```

Comment: ....by writing your own method

Comment: pointing me in the right direction wont kill you

Comment: sorry, I thought you were asking how to modify the behaviour of Arrays.toString() - which you cant do. I've posted some code that prints what you want as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by writing your own print method.  something like this:

```
    public static String fancyPrint(Object... array) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int total = 0;
        for (Object o : array) {
            output.append(o.toString());
            total+=1;
            if (total%3==0) {
                output.append(" ---> ");
            } else {
                output.append(", ");
            }
        }
        //remove last ", " or " ---> " printed
        if (total%3==0) {
            output.delete(output.length()-" ---> ".length(), output.length());
        } else {
            output.delete(output.length()-", ".length(), output.length());
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

Comment: okay this helps, just a few questions. You have it just putting the "-->" after the 3rd term but I need it after the first 2 as well. Also this program isn't always going to have 4 terms so I need to have an arrow after each term except the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You could trim your array first by number of elements before converting it into string. So you would run toString() on pieces of array. Now use these smaller strings and print them in the order desirable. If you think for trimming, you have to form new sub-arrays and it would waste memory, you could also just print out the array one member at a time.