# Java: Can an array ever be output without making it a string?

Tags: java

When doing practice problems that require an array as it's output, I have to use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayName));
```

Is that the only way to visually see what array you end up with?  And if so, is there any way to change the format of the output?

By default the Arrays.toString method puts [ ] around the array and puts a space after each comma.  What if instead of [0, 1, 2, 3], I wanted to display the array as {0,1,2,3}?

I know this is trivial, but it just seems odd that we are limited to how an array can be displayed.

Comment: You can iterate through it and print each element separately, adding whatever delimiters you like.

Comment: "seems odd that we are limited to how an array can be displayed" You are not. You can do whatever. But by default it displayed in a way so that you or anyone else looking at it would know that it is an array and not something else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15818208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way I can think of for displaying arrays is by iterating over the array with a for loop.

```
int[] numbers = {1, 5, 3};
// then you can print out the curly braces
System.out.print("{");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    if (!(i == numbers.length-1)) System.out.print(",");
}
System.out.print("}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:  no.  That's just the most convenient way to do it.

Depending on your requirements, you can iterate the array in several different ways to get the data you need, and display it in whichever way you require.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with the Apache Commons `StringUtils.join` method ( see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.String)), where you can specify a separator.  You can add the `{` and `}` characters separately yourself.

```
System.out.println("{" + StringUtils.join(myArray, ",") + "}");
```

Comment: Eclipse isn't natively recognizing the class StringUtils or the join method.  Do I have to import the class from the link you gave first?  if so, can you explain how.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to get the Apache Commons Lang jar from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ and put it in your classpath.

Comment: @ David Wallace.  Thanks David.  I'm new to installing jars.  The link provides key signing links.  Do I need to bother with those or is that only if I'm downloading from a mirror?